# How do I add a dependency package for react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I found the code for a React hook in GitHub and downloaded it to a new folder on my PC. How do I now make this available for use in an existing React project that I am working with in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: You don't need to manually download it. Just run `npm install <package_name>` or whatever the instruction says in the GitHub page, in your React project's root folder.

Comment: I think he just found a custom Hook code he wants to use. If so, then you just create a folder "Hooks" and create a file where you will copy paste this Hook's code.

Comment: Thank you both. The answer from @technophyle worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse for different dependencies from [npm.js](https://www.npmjs.com/).
You can install the dependency with your package manager, for e.g., `npm install <package_name>` or `yarn add <package_name>` or `pnpm add <package_name>`